# text loading delay in android activity

Tags: android

Given below is the (onCreate) code that I use to display some information on a screen of my android app. This activity is getting loaded on a event triggered in another activity. The problem is when this screen is loaded. It first loads the blank screen and then it renders the relevant text on it with a delay. This delay can be noticed by the end user and it makes them feel like screen is getting loaded twice. Is there any solution for this?

[image: First it loads the UI]

[image: Then after a delay it loads the relevant text]

```
@Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_end);
                CommonUtils.changeActionBarColor(getSupportActionBar());

                //get the respective child object which has to be displayed in the GUI
                String childObjectKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(CHILD_OBJECT_KEY);
                // Single method pop(), for both pushWeak() and pushStrong()
                endObject = (IPEnd) ASFObjectStore.getDefault().pop(childObjectKey);

                this.setTitle(endObject.getPathwayName());

                //endWebView
                WebView endWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.endWebView);
                String tempEndString = HTMLConverter.changeFontSize(endObject.getEndText(), UtilConstants.GLOBAL_FONT_SIZE);
                tempEndString = HTMLConverter.changeFontFamily(tempEndString,UtilConstants.GLOBAL_FONT_FAMILY);
                endWebView.loadData(tempEndString,"text/html;charset=utf-8","UTF-8");

                //overall image button
                ImageButton overviewButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.endOverviewImageButton);
                overviewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //showOverviewImage("Bleeding (First Trimester).jpg");
                        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
                        Button btnClosePopup = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
                        String imageFileName = endObject.getPathwayName()+ UtilConstants.IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSION;

                        CommonUtils utils = new CommonUtils();
                        utils.showOverviewImage(imageFileName, getWindowManager(), getApplicationContext(), layoutInflater, view,End.this);
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: This delay seems to be caused by the webviews included in the activity. There are multiple webviews used in this screen. They are taking time to load the text.